# Make new Animation impossible when Animation is running (disable setOnMouseClicked during Animation)

Tags: java, javafx

I've been searching all over for a way to do this, but I seem to be unable to find a solution for javafx (I only find it in jQuery and javascript).
I have a game where you can rotate tiles (ImageViews) on Mouseclick and I do that with

```
setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            update();
        }
    };
```

And update has this:

```
public void update() {
    Animation animation = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(100), this);
    animation.setByAngle(90);
    animation.play();
    tile.rotate();
}
```

The problem is, when I click too fast on the tile (while it's still rotating) it gets screwed up and gets stuck at for example 60 degrees.
I just want to make it so it's impossible to click the imageView while the animation is running.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a boolean storing whether the function is currently running and disable/enable it accordingly.

```
boolean currentlyPlaying = false;
node.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (!currentlyPlaying)
        update();
});
public void update() {
    Animation animation = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(100), this);
    animation.setByAngle(90);
    animation.play();
    currentlyPlaying = true;
    animation.setOnFinished(event -> currentlyPlaying = false;);
    tile.rotate();
}
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to make that flag an `AtomicBoolean` object? Or would that be unnecessary?

Comment: A regular boolean stored globally should work just fine.

Comment: perfect! So easy and yet I couldn't solve it myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another option, rather than creating a separate `boolean` variable, is to use the [`status` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#statusProperty) of `Animation`. You can also reuse the same `Animation` for every tile.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

  private RotateTransition transition;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    root.setHgap(15);
    root.setVgap(15);

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClick = this::handleClick;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(onClick);
        root.add(rect, i, j);
      }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Animation Example");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void handleClick(MouseEvent event) {
    if (transition == null) {
      transition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(100));
      transition.setByAngle(90);
    } else if (transition.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
      return;
    }

    transition.setNode((Rectangle) event.getSource());
    transition.playFromStart();
    event.consume();
  }

}
```

This code will only start a new transition if one is not currently running. Note, however, that this setup only allows one tile to rotate at any given time. If you would like to have an animation per tile this requires a small adjustment.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

  private final Map<Rectangle, RotateTransition> animations = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    root.setHgap(15);
    root.setVgap(15);

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClick = this::handleClick;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(onClick);
        root.add(rect, i, j);
      }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Animation Example");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void handleClick(MouseEvent event) {
    RotateTransition animation = animations.computeIfAbsent((Rectangle) event.getSource(), rect -> {
      RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(100), rect);
      rt.setByAngle(90);
      return rt;
    });

    if (animation.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING) {
      animation.playFromStart();
      event.consume();
    }
  }

}
```

Now each tile has its own `RotateTransition` but the animation will only be played if it isn't already running.